# What type of tool has hooked jaws and a threaded shaft with a T-handle?

Tags: tools

I found this tool and do not know what is called or used for.

[image]

Answer (score 10):

It is a copper tube flaring tool.  There should be another part to it, a clamp that will hold different size copper pipes.

If you ever use one, make sure you put the nut on the pipe before flaring (not that I ever forgot to do that).

[image]

Comment: With the very straight "rammer" (or whatever it's called)? I'm not any sort of expert, but I thought the flare was more rounded than that.

Comment: @FreeMan  The base clamp has a bit more "roundness" to it and forms the copper

Comment: I never forgot the flare nut either, if I did it was just because I was doing a practise run :)

Comment: Smaller versions are available to flare steel (as they used to be) or other metal brake pipes on cars.

Comment: @Tim  Yes, and they have special inserts to make double flares

Comment: Yes, still have my Snap-on kit from 50 yrs ago!